# Combobox Databind() check

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql

I have a combobox and a list of values in it. 
If I add a value and save it, it should appear in the combobox. But it only appears after I refresh the page. It does not bind the data properly.

I have put DataBind() in

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
DataBind() ;
}
```

But the above does not help.
How do I check if everything is binding correctly or not.

Please help.
Thank you

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 DataBind();
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
}
}



protected void btn_save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)

            {
    SqlCommand command_update = new SqlCommand("Update", connection_save1); 
                        command_update.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                        command_update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ViewId", Int32.Parse(Id.Value)));
    SqlParameter Returns = new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Char);
                        Returns.Size = 1;
                        Returns.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        command_insert.Parameters.Add(Returns);
     bSuccess = command_insert.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value.ToString();
    if (bSuccess == "1")
                        {
                            //Response.Write("Insert successful");
                            dd_group.DataBind();
                            dd_group.SelectedValue = command_insert.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value.ToString().Trim();
    }
    }
```

here is the html

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd_group" DataSourceID="sp" DataTextField="maintitle"
                        DataValueField="Id" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="group_SelectedIndexChanged1" Height="24px" 
                        Width="50%">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sp" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="GetIds" runat="server" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Pre_Render(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 DataBind();

}



protected void btn_save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)

            {
    SqlCommand command_update = new SqlCommand("Update", connection_save1); 
                        command_update.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                        command_update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ViewId", Int32.Parse(Id.Value)));
    SqlParameter Returns = new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Char);
                        Returns.Size = 1;
                        Returns.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        command_insert.Parameters.Add(Returns);
     bSuccess = command_insert.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value.ToString();
    if (bSuccess == "1")
                        {
                            //Response.Write("Insert successful");
                            dd_group.DataBind();
                            dd_group.SelectedValue = command_insert.Parameters["@ReturnCode"].Value.ToString().Trim();
    }
    }
```

Comment: is there a requires or expects datasource property by chance on that particular control..? if so add your DataBind() or BindData() there

Comment: I tried putting Databind() in the exact position as you describe it. But no luck :(

Comment: I have a better solution:   BindGroupId.DataSource = whatever;
                    BindGroupId.DataTextField = "column name";                 
                    BindGroupId.DataValueField = "value";
                    BindGroupId.DataBind();

Comment: @Ish I have better solution : the  DataValueField  and  DataTextField  should be written in the aspx code and not in the CS code......

Answer (score 1):

you can use a webmethod to add elements to the combobox and when you add any item use jquery or even javascript and call this webmthod where u rebind the data

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `DataBind()` after you update your data source: this is normally done in some control event handler which is called after `Page_Load()` event and therefore this invocation is only visible after your refresh (then it is called for the second time, the first time after your update).

So, just add `DataBind()` to your method where you perform the update, something like:

```
mycontrol.DataSource = newvariable;
mycontrol.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am not understading the reasoning behind this

Comment: I don't see any `DataContext` assignment in your code? How to you perform data binding?